# sudden error after working well for hours: recursion error maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, google-api, raspberry-pi4

i'm using arduino to feed data via serial to raspi 4 that then uploades it to google sheets via google api.

things were working well for some time but now for some unknown reason, the logging stopped in the middle of the night. when i looked at the pycharm command line i saw a huge pile of commands (i didn't copy it all, just the last screen) :

```
   File "/home/pi/Downloads/WATER PROJECT/MAIN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/WATER PROJECT/MAIN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/WATER PROJECT/MAIN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/WATER PROJECT/MAIN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/WATER PROJECT/MAIN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 320, in begin
self.headers = self.msg = parse_headers(self.fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 214, in parse_headers
return email.parser.Parser(_class=_class).parsestr(hstring)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/parser.py", line 68, in parsestr
return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/parser.py", line 57, in parse
feedparser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/feedparser.py", line 176, in feed
self._call_parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/feedparser.py", line 180, in _call_parse
self._parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/feedparser.py", line 256, in _parsegen
if self._cur.get_content_type() == 'message/delivery-status':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/message.py", line 578, in get_content_type
value = self.get('content-type', missing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/message.py", line 471, in get
return self.policy.header_fetch_parse(k, v)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/_policybase.py", line 316, in header_fetch_parse
return self._sanitize_header(name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/_policybase.py", line 287, in _sanitize_header
if _has_surrogates(value):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/email/utils.py", line 57, in _has_surrogates
s.encode()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the code i'm using:

```
import logging
import random
import time
import serial
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime


def init_connection(ser, last_experiment=None):
    """
    This function is used to initialize the connection with google's system.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param last_experiment: If none - it is a normal experiment but else can be used to continue a running experiment
    :return:
    """
    # Use credentials to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    # Make sure you use the right name here
    spread_sheet = client.open("EXPERIMENTS")
    init_experiment(ser, spread_sheet, last_experiment=last_experiment)


def init_experiment(ser, spread_sheet, last_experiment=None):
    """
    This function is used to initialize the experiment: create a new worksheet for the experiment and set it up.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param spread_sheet: The spreadsheet of the experiment.
    :param last_experiment: If none - it is a normal experiment but else can be used to continue a running experiment
    :return:
    """
    experiment_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    print(spread_sheet.title + "@" + experiment_time)
    logging.log(100, spread_sheet.title + "@" + experiment_time)

    # create new worksheet
    if last_experiment is None:
        worksheet = spread_sheet.add_worksheet(title="experiment@" + experiment_time, rows=10000, cols=15)
    else:
        worksheet = spread_sheet.worksheet(last_experiment[0])
    # add titles
    worksheet.update_acell('A1', 't')
    worksheet.update_acell('B1', 'T_1')
    worksheet.update_acell('C1', 'T_2')
    worksheet.update_acell('D1', 'T_3')
    worksheet.update_acell('E1', 'T_4')
    worksheet.update_acell('F1', 'T_5')
    worksheet.update_acell('G1', 'T_6')
    worksheet.update_acell('H1', 'RH_1')
    worksheet.update_acell('I1', 'RH_2')
    worksheet.update_acell('J1', 'RH_3')
    worksheet.update_acell('K1', 'RH_4')
    worksheet.update_acell('L1', 'RH_5')
    worksheet.update_acell('M1', 'RH_6')
    worksheet.update_acell('N1', 'FLOW')
    worksheet.update_acell('O1', 'WEIGHT')

    print("t, T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, T_5, T_6, RH_1, RH_2, RH_3, RH_4, RH_5, RH_6, FLOW, WEIGHT")
    logging.log(100, "t, T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, T_5, T_6, RH_1, RH_2, RH_3, RH_4, RH_5, RH_6, FLOW, WEIGHT")

    # start experiment loop
    if last_experiment is None:
        start_experiment(ser, worksheet=worksheet)
    else:
        start_experiment(ser, worksheet=worksheet, worksheet_row=last_experiment[1])


def start_experiment(ser, worksheet, worksheet_row=2):
    """
    The experiment loop, measure the sensors and update the sheet.
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :param worksheet: The specific sheet we edit
    :param worksheet_row: The row we're writing at
    :return:
    """
    print(worksheet_row)
    while True:
        try:
            # get measurements and cell range:
            measurements = get_measurements(ser)
            print("vals=" + str(measurements))
            logging.log(100, "vals=" + str(measurements))
            cell_list = worksheet.range('A' + str(worksheet_row) + ':O' + str(worksheet_row))

            # update in sheets
            for i in range(len(measurements)):
                cell_list[i].value = measurements[i]
            worksheet.update_cells(cell_list, 'USER_ENTERED')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            logging.log(100, e)
            time.sleep(100)
            init_connection(ser, last_experiment=(worksheet.title, worksheet_row))
        # next row and wait for some time
        worksheet_row += 1
        time.sleep(30)


def get_measurements(ser):
    """
    This function measures the sensors of the experiment
    :param ser: The reference to the serial object we use to communicate with the ATMega328P
    :return: Array of the measurement according to this order: t, T_in, T_out, T_aux, RH_in, RH_out,         RH_aux, Flux,WaterLevel
    """
    t = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    # Here we read the data from the sensors
    T_1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    T_2 = random.randint(1, 10) + 15
    T_3 = random.randint(1, 3) - 5
    T_4 = random.randint(1, 4)
    T_5 = random.randint(1, 10) + 13
    T_6 = random.randint(1, 3) - 7
    RH_1 = random.randint(1, 5) + 55
    RH_2 = random.randint(1, 5) + 40
    RH_3 = random.randint(1, 5) + 50
    RH_4 = random.randint(1, 5) + 53
    RH_5 = random.randint(1, 5) + 42
    RH_6 = random.randint(1, 5) + 51
    FLOW = random.randint(1, 100) + 400
    WEIGHT = random.randint(1, 100) + 5

    data = [ser.read()]
    if data[0] != b'':
        newByte = ser.read()
        while newByte != b'':
            data.append(newByte)
            newByte = ser.read()
        data = b''.join(data)
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        print('data_read=' + str(data))
        data = data.split('\n')
        list_of_parameters = ['t=', 'T1=', 'RH1=', 'T2=', 'RH2=', 'T3=', 'RH3=', 'T4=', 'RH4=', 'T5=', 'RH5=', 'T6=', 'RH6=', 'FLOW=', 'WEIGHT='] #need to be exactly the same as written in the arduino serial monitor
        for line in data:
          if any(x not in line for x in list_of_parameters):
            data.remove(line)

        data = data[len(data) - 1]        

        print('data=' + str(data))
        data = data.split(' ')
        uptime= (data[0])[data[0].index('=') + 1:]
        T_1= (data[1])[data[1].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_1 = (data[2])[data[2].index('=') + 1:]
        T_2 = (data[3])[data[3].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_2 = (data[4])[data[4].index('=') + 1:]
        T_3 = (data[5])[data[5].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_3 = (data[6])[data[6].index('=') + 1:]
        T_4 = (data[7])[data[7].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_4 = (data[8])[data[8].index('=') + 1:]
        T_5 = (data[9])[data[9].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_5 = (data[10])[data[10].index('=') + 1:]
        T_6 = (data[11])[data[11].index('=') + 1:]
        RH_6 = (data[12])[data[12].index('=') + 1:]
        FLOW = (data[13])[data[13].index('=') + 1:]
        WEIGHT = (data[14])[data[14].index('=') + 1:]

    return t, T_1, T_2, T_3,T_4, T_5, T_6, RH_1, RH_2, RH_3, RH_4, RH_5, RH_6,FLOW,WEIGHT


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/experiment@' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") +'.log', filemode='w',
                    level=100, format="")
    print('Initializing program')
    logging.log(100, 'Initializing program')

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=0.1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Serial connection is okay')
    logging.log(100, 'Serial connection is okay')

    init_connection(ser)
```

i'm suspecting the source of error to be internet problems, but then again - the internet in the building is working just fine. and now it is also working fine. did anyone experience this or can tell me how to troubleshoot this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like an issue with your internet connection or an internal module.  Nothing in the exception refers specifically to your code.  Without digging too deep into it, I'd bet that your internet went down overnight for a while and the module you're using to connect to the Google API was recursively trying to reconnect.  Just my hunches.

Comment: can you recommend a procedure to test the internet connection in the raspi? 
i'm pretty sure the internet of the facility i reside in didn't go down.

also, how can i implement a line of code that will restart the data logging process in case the internet goes down temporarily?

Comment: I'd recommend adding some try/except blocks around your code that uses an internet connection.  When it catches an exception, it just restarts the connection.  Not a perfect solution, but it should fix your problem.  Check the very top of your exception to find the last bit of your code that was involved in the recursion error.  Off the top of my head can't think of an easy way to test the internet connection with the raspi other than pinging Google's DNS, but I'm not sure how much that would help.